# login with facebook in phonegap 4.2

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new in phonegap and i am tring to login with facebook in phonegap using [phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

i think there are some problem in my setup.

i have installed this plugin and add plugin in config.xml file.

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="1547160042188072" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="XXXXXXXXXXX" />
    </gap:plugin>
```

there is folder in plugin folder named as  `com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect`. so i think plugin is add in project.
here is my html where i call the fb login fuinction

```
<a href="javascript:fbLogin()"><img src="images/btnFB.png"  class="socialimg"></a>
```

my function is

```
function fbLogin(){
        var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
            alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
        }

        facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
            fbLoginSuccess,
            function (error) { alert("" + error) }
        );
    }
```

when i call this function it gives error :

```
03-20 09:18:05.782: D/CordovaActivity(2607): Resuming the App
03-20 09:18:15.852: W/System.err(2607): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin
03-20 09:18:15.942: W/System.err(2607):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-20 09:18:15.942: W/System.err(2607):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
03-20 09:18:15.962: W/System.err(2607):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
03-20 09:18:15.962: W/System.err(2607):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.instantiatePlugin(PluginManager.java:345)
03-20 09:18:15.962: W/System.err(2607):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:189)
03-20 09:18:15.982: W/System.err(2607):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:137)
03-20 09:18:15.982: W/System.err(2607):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
03-20 09:18:15.992: W/System.err(2607):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)
03-20 09:18:15.992: W/System.err(2607):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
03-20 09:18:15.992: W/System.err(2607):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
03-20 09:18:15.992: W/System.err(2607):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-20 09:18:15.992: W/System.err(2607):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-20 09:18:15.992: W/System.err(2607):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-20 09:18:15.992: W/System.err(2607): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cordova/facebook/ConnectPlugin
03-20 09:18:15.992: W/System.err(2607):     ... 13 more
03-20 09:18:16.022: W/System.err(2607): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.syonserver.couponspring-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.syonserver.couponspring-1, /system/lib]]
03-20 09:18:16.042: W/System.err(2607):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-20 09:18:16.042: W/System.err(2607):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-20 09:18:16.042: W/System.err(2607):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-20 09:18:16.042: W/System.err(2607):     ... 13 more
03-20 09:18:16.052: I/System.out(2607): Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin.
03-20 09:18:16.052: W/System.err(2607): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 09:18:16.052: W/System.err(2607):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:191)
03-20 09:18:16.052: W/System.err(2607):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:137)
03-20 09:18:16.052: W/System.err(2607):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
03-20 09:18:16.052: W/System.err(2607):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)
03-20 09:18:16.052: W/System.err(2607):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
03-20 09:18:16.062: W/System.err(2607):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
03-20 09:18:16.062: W/System.err(2607):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-20 09:18:16.062: W/System.err(2607):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-20 09:18:16.062: W/System.err(2607):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for your ConnectPlugin class to be in the org.apache.cordova.facebook namespace. Check either what you have set for the package at the top of your ConnectPlugin.java file or under the org.apache.cordova.facebook namespace is there any file named ConnectPlugin.java.

The moto is that you have to kept a file under the org.apache.cordova.facebook namespace and name should be ConnectPlugin.java